# How to trigger or refresh the search results on the basis of a session variable?

Tags: sxa, search-facet

I have a page with the SXA search result component. I want to refresh the search result on the click of a button. Please let me know if it is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to update **hash** in the URL (search parameters)

*Search Results* will reload once hash parameter in the URL will change.

You can do it like this

```javascript
window.location.hash = "foo=1"
```

You can add parameter that does nothing like I did and increment its value.
To trigger it again you will have to assign different value (`"foo=2"`).

If you have other search renderings on a page which add their own parameters to the hash you will have to fetch current value, modify it and then assign.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! It is working .But in the page I have 2 search result component, the 2nd one is getting empty while the 1st one is refreshed please suggest.How can i know which hash to use for 2nd one?

Comment: Can i use the searchresultsignature?

Comment: Assuming that your search configuration is correct (signatures) you don't have to worry about parameters, you just have to update 'fake' parameter and that's it

Comment: As I said it is making the 2nd search results blank